# Two way web service communication in wpf

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, wpf

I have a `WPF` application that needs to send and fetch data to and from a web application. Web application is built using ruby on rails.

What's confusing me at the moment is does the `WPF` application need to have a `web/wcf` service on it's own to talk to the rails web application web service. If not how can i fetch and send data to and from the rails web application web service.

Please note that I have done some digging around google and here but am still confused since most of talk of creating a asp.net application first. A step by step best guess scenario/example would really be helpful.

Comment: your ROR app just wants an HTTP request for the service, right? Can you post what a typical call would look like?